# asp.net mvc using audit trial logging

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Create a UI to allow user to search for the record in the audit table.
UI consists of 2 parts: (A) Search Criteria (B) Search Result
(A) Search Criteria. Position it at top of page. Search Criteria should contains the following search fields,
Username ,Audit DateFrom ,to,Audit Time From,to,Old Value,New value
(B) Search Result. Position it below (A).
Display in a tabular format with header label same as (A)
2. Create UI for View of select record at the search screen. Details should contains,
ID
Username
IsUser
Time
Action
Table Name
Old Value
New Value

create a search and view functionality on the audit table. No create, edit, and delete needed
 need some sample code...

Comment: sounds like homework... not a genuine question.

Comment: This also sounds like a work request, not a question. You can't just post assignments on StackOverflow for people to do for you without first having a go yourself and getting stuck on something...

Answer (score 0):

Have done something similar using SQL Views in ASP.NET MVC. See the attached screenshot and let me know if you are looking for something similar

http://www.naweed.info/TempFiles/MagnetAuditTrail.jpg